# What is a neat way to patch a webapp deployed using XAMPP?

Tags: java, installation, xampp, upgrade, patch

I have a Spring webapp. It is distributed using XAMPP (usually deployed on Windows) so that non-technical users can conveniently install it.
Now if I want to patch the webapp alone in the XAMPP software. It would be convenient if I can reduce the download footprint of the patch and apply it.

An executable that I can double click on. Shuts down the database. It automatically checks for updates at a preconfigured URL and patches the webapp within the XAMPP installation without affecting the MySQL database.

Is there some out of the box solution available or do I need to build a custom one?

Additionally a neat way to apply schema changes (like addding a new column) to MySQL database without deleting any data will also be useful.

Comment: share a binary with them which executes a simple batch script (or shell script on unix) which: deploys the war, restarts services. Now, database schema change might be more involved, not sure how can you automate that.

Comment: Thanks @zengr I was thinking of this ... but is there a way to make the process of patching more automated ... so I do not have to write the batch script again and again, only the diff is sent to them. If there is an off the shelf solution, it will be wonderful.

Comment: well, I don't distribute my web app to client devices, but the way I push my source code to server is using fabric + git. A fabric script does a git pull, git gets the diff. Then fabric restarts server etc. but you cannot do all that since you need to be cross platform. (you cannot get your clients install python,pip,fabric,git)

Comment: If it is worth it I can bundle python along with the software. But my major concern is that once the software has shipped - it should be possible to patch it with just a double click. MySQL is shipped with XAMPP. I can write a script to compute the diffs between the two versions and apply the diffs on all executables, jars whatever. But I do not want the client to do anything and data should not be affected. modifying mysql tables is tricky so I think I should avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

For upgrading databases we use Flyway, a library which allows you to upgrade your database to a specific version of your application with a single command. It also keeps track of your database's version and allows you to perform a downgrade/rollback when required.

http://flywaydb.org

Comment: Thanks Rein ... WEB-INF directory. I need to ensure the server is not running, find the diffs and prepare a custom upgrade patch for delivery. Should I just rollout my own script? For database I will look into Flyway.